# Placeholder In PhoneGap for password Type not working

Tags: cordova, placeholder

The Following  placeholder Code Not Working in phonegap windows phone

```
<input type="text" id="TxtName"  style="margin-left:45px" placeholder="Enter Name" />
<input type="password" id="TxtPass" style="margin-left:20px" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try also putting value="" into the input fields.